# Много xml активностей java в kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Возможно кто-то подскажет, как это решить...

Все знают, что переключаться между активностями java и xml файлами, например

```
layout.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, layout_menu::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Но вот что делать, если таких активностей много layout.xml например 1000 или 10000, что делать в таком случае?

Моё решение, как вариант подключать через сервер, не могу найти... Может кто знает как?

**Причина:**
Эти активности пытался создать много, но в итоге android studio начал притормаживать.

Comment: Думаю, что вы делаете что-то не так, раз вам нужно 1000 xml и активностей. Опишите **актуальную** проблему из-за которой вам понадобилось столько xml и активностей, а то сейчас выглядит как XY проблема

Comment: Я не понял вопрос. Xml это не активность, а разметка.

Comment: @ir42 Как бы точно объяснить, нужен именно каждый раз новый интерфейс, то есть переключение на xml файлы, как бы этакий слайдер с 1000 разных элементов с картинками, текстом, тормозит не само приложение, а сама программа из-за много добавленных xml файлов в layout

Comment: используйте для этого RecyclerView или ViewPager(ViewPager2)

Comment: @IR42 Вариант подходит ViewPager, а возможно использовать ViewFlipper?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще 10к активностей и даже 1к это оч много. Прям совсем дофига если быть точным (цензура не позволяет более точно указать кол-во). Я бы вам советовал:

1. Использовать фрагменты - они легче чем активность и по механизму почти ничем не отличаются. Одна активность будет как контейнер и будете фрагменты менять когда вам нужно. Вот есть туториалы по фрагментам: [1](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php) и [2](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/175-urok-105-android-3-fragments-dinamicheskaja-rabota.html).
2. Попытайтесь вычленить похожие данные - если у вас там приблизительно одинаковые данные на ваших экранах то попытайтесь это оптимизировать. Внедрить динамическую обработку изменения данных и передачу данных.

Если у вас тормозит студия, на ПК у которого минимум 8гб озу то что уже говорить за обычные мобильные телефоны у которых ресурсов намного меньше. Через сервер я ооочень сильно сомневаюсь, разве что сервер вам будет возвращать идентификатор активности на которую нужно перейти. Но будет два нюанса - поддерживать такое будет очень трудоемко и так никто не делает :) Проведите оптимизационную работу, и судя по тому что у вас 1к разметок то очень большую работу. Так не делает никто :) Нужно чтобы все было максимально сжато и компактно :)

Так же небольшое уточнение:

1. файлы с расширением `.java` или `.kt` это файлы которые представляют собой объекты класса android.app.Activity, которая содержит базовую функциональность для всех activity.
2. файлы c расширением `.xml` это файлы разметки (и не только) которые отвечают за внешнее оформление экрана пользователя

Используя приведенное выше уточнение я бы вам советовал немного отредактировать вопрос